# Is there a library repository for C?

Tags: c, repository, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there is not a comprehensive c archive network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080696/why-there-is-not-a-comprehensive-c-archive-network)

Everyone knows that C is very small language, it has just language primitives and almost no standard library (no data structures or algorithms).

Therefore I have a question, how do I find good C libraries for data structures, algorithms and perhaps system programming?

For example, if I need a hash-table, how do I find a good implementation? Or for example, if I need to work with graphs, what do I do?

So far I have been writing everything myself. But my hash table implementation is nowhere good enough. It's very basic.

What do advanced C programmers do with this problem? Do they really write all the libraries again themselves?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Most of the programming related internet...c is so pervasive that it has never needed a central repository. Well, that and it predates the world wide web by circa 25 years...

Comment: Yeah but, C++ has STL, Boost, etc, you might expect something similar for pure C libs..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080696/why-there-is-not-a-comprehensive-c-archive-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't anything as "go to" as Boost in C++ (STL doesn't count as its part of the standard).

Beyond GLib, there is [APR](http://apr.apache.org/)

Answer (score 6):

[GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/).

Answer (score 1):

http://directory.fsf.org/category/clibs/

Answer (score 1):

http://ccan.ozlabs.org/

EDIT: CCAN has moved domains to https://ccodearchive.net/

Comment: The link returns 404. A working one is [CCAN link](https://ccodearchive.net/)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any set way.... there's just a proliferation of all kinds of frameworks out there.  Often there is different forces on what people want, eg,  depending if its for embedded systems, PCs, flavor of OS, or whatever.