# Is there a repository of C libraries?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there is not a comprehensive c archive network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080696/why-there-is-not-a-comprehensive-c-archive-network)

Like Python has a Cheeseshop and Perl has CPAN?
Google results have a lot of C++ results and I am looking for purely C libraries.

PS: Looking for *nix libraries

Comment: Note also an second earlier version [Is there a library repository for C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129809/is-there-a-library-repository-for-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. SourceForge, Codeplex, Github, and Google.  Also, your distro's packages, if you are on Linux.

Comment: +1 for distro packages, it's surprising what headers/libs can be found in there... not quite so much use if your writing for windows though...

Comment: Sourceforge is useful but it only lists stuff that's hosted there - same problem with Github. I was looking for something that is more definitive.

Comment: There is no definitive collection of C libraries, not in the sense that you are after.  Perl has CPAN because it was started very near to when Perl started gaining traction, so everybody used it.  The only thing comparable for C is really the whole Internet. :/

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. Google is really your best friend. Since C doesn't have a standardized body running the language in the same way as, say, Python, there is no central place for packages and marketing material.

Your best bet really is your local Linux distribution - Linux applications generally make heavy use of many layers of libraries, which you can use as a reference.

Comment: Google isn't really effective because there is a lot of C++ results and I am looking for purely C libraries.

Comment: Yes, C++ gets in the way when searching for C. May be a -C++ can help. But not very effective in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [CCAN](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/) (although I'm not sure how good it is - never really used it).